# How can I stop KDE apps from being shown in the Software Centre?

Tags: software-center, kde

Their size is so **big**, that's why I will never download any of them so they're just been in my way to find the **native** software that am willing to download from **Ubuntu software center**, so is there is anyway to **delete** their **PPA** or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You cannot, but try Synaptic instead

Most KDE apps are in the official repositories and not in a PPA, so there's no way to prevent them being shown when you browse/search in the Software Centre.

As an alternative, try installing the Synaptic Package Manager instead, and look at the listings under the "Gnome Desktop Environment" sections for a selection of "native" apps:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing thing, I like to stay with USC so I guess will have to learn to live with them being around :)